# UIFileSharingEnabled but Documents list empty in iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to enable File Sharing for my app. Basically, I need to write something into a csv file using the app, then transfer the csv file from iPad to my macbook via iTunes.

So far, I've added UIFileSharingEnabled to my plist and set that to YES.

I've also put the following code in my app:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv",fileName];

NSString *docName = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dName];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docName contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:docName];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
NSLog(@"file saved");
NSLog(@"%@",docName);
```

Now, the interesting thing is, in the NSlog, it is confirmed that the file has been created and saved.

```
MyApp[3674:60b] file saved
MyApp[3674:60b] /var/mobile/Applications/9532F76D-C5D2-4B46-A7BA-7AA24009553B/Documents/TEST.csv
```

And in iTunes, MyApp is listed in the FileSharing App list. But, the Documents list on its right is completely empty. No matter what.

Please tell me where did I do wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this code:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docName contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

With:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docName]){
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docName contents:nil attributes:nil];
    NSLog(@"%d,",success);
}
```